# Is using @ts-ignore fine in here?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am using typescript with express. When I call `findById` of a `mongoose model` I get it of type `SomeModel|null`.

I have an express handler like below:-

```
async function myHandler(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        let model = await myModel.findById(req.params.id);
        if (!model) {
            //forward to 404 handler
            next();
        }
        res.send({
            //@ts-ignore
            model: model.someFunc()
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

I am suppressing the `typescript compiler` here as the control will never reach `res.send` with the `null` value. But is there an elegant way of telling this to `tsc`? or is it fine to use `//@ts-ignore` here?

Comment: The `res.send` call still happens. Are you missing a `return` or `else {` here?

Comment: Can it happen without a `return` statement? As when I call next it goes to next handler which is a `404` handler in my case which returns `not found`. The error vanished when I added return :)

Comment: I don't understand.  If `model` is `null`, then you call `next()`.  Does `next()` throw an exception?  If not, then after `next()` returns, `myHandler` will proceed to call `model.someFunc()` on the null value.  That's what TypeScript is complaining about.